# Internet disconnects every 2 minutes everyday for months, solutions?

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection, isp, adsl

Calling ISP does nothing, they send a guy to check my cabinate and he sees nothing wrong and nothing wrong at the exchange. They check the line and they say it can handle 16mb. yet it cant even handle 2mb! at 2mb its constant disconnections with no hope of downloading or streaming (spotify doesnt work).

My ISP (TeData) is the main on in the country, with a monopoly they dont care all that much since they like to upload viruses and block news sites. My area is in a central part of the city and close to the exchange. No one i know has the same problem as me. Ive tried different routers and all that to see if the issue is on my end but nothing. The last time i called, they checked the exchange and it got worse.

[image: ADSL statistics from router]

Comment: From what your router lists, your connection seems to be excellent (ignoring the fact it doesn't seem to negotiate the max data rate).

Comment: When you say internet disconnects, does your router lose synchronization (typically makes some LED flash) or is only the internet disconnected? Any chance its just an issue with your local wifi or LAN network?

Comment: led is off then after a while it flashes on again, takes about a minute. The PC, the phones, everthing reports the same. Every router tried same, every setting, using Google DNS or ISP, also same. The ISP themselves dont know what is at fault.

Comment: current rate, is done automatically based on ISP's detection of my lines stability. 3mb or 2mb are as unstable as higher but less so. The higher i go in speed the more unstable. The more traffic hours, the more unstable as well (weekends, evenings).

Comment: You could try to convince them to condition your line, i.e. test for and remove bridged taps. It's a job that could consume a few hours, so it's not often done for ADSL (but is required for real T1). I also had static on the voice channel, so that's why the lineman had to perform the TDS.

Comment: Would they be aware of bridge taps? For me whats odd, is they dont believe there is anything wrong. They dont even know what to look for. I cant convince them. The only way for them to take it seriously if I lie and say i cant connect at all, or that the entire area has problems and the problem is getting worse.

Comment: *"Would they be aware of bridge taps?"* -- Only if the tech has the equipment and training.  xDSL was intended to *not* require removal of bridged taps, but that's theory versus reality.  In my case, the deterioration of a 30+ years-old copper loop was too much for the ADSL electronics to overcome.  Read http://www.exfo.com/corporate/blog/2010/bridged-tap-detection-made-simple  *"I cant convince them."* -- If you've given up or not going to do anything, then stop bothering us with questions.

Comment: i got an technician ISP sent today, but all he suggested was a splitter or filter, which i aldready know doesnt work. Thats all. I had to throw all possibilities at him at what could be the problem from what i gathered here and other sites, but didnt seem to be too familar. They mostly only get called in for what he said "router problems". I think i will need to call telephone company instead but dont know what to tell them to get them to troubleshoot.